# Get all descendants in a tree in javascript

Tags: javascript

Given a basic tree like this:

```
[
  {
    id: "1"
  },
  {
    id: "2"
  },
  {
    id: "3"
  },
  {
    id: "2.1",
    parent_id: "2"
  },
  {
    id: "3.1",
    parent_id: "3"
  },
  {
    id: "3.2",
    parent_id: "3"
  },
  {
    id: "3.1.1",
    parent_id: "3.1"
  },
  {
    id: "3.1.1.1",
    parent_id: "3.1.1"
  },
  {
    id: "3.1.1.1.1",
    parent_id: "3.1.1.1"
  },
  {
    id: "bohemian rhapsody",
    parent_id: "3.2"
  }
]
```

I want to be able to get all descendants starting at an arbitrary level (id).

This works but I am questioning if this is the most efficient way to do this because essentially I am scanning the array at each level

```
let source = []; // my array here
let getDescendants = (id, source) => {
    let result = [];
  
    for (let node of source) {
     if (node.id === id) {
        result.push(node);
     } else if (node.parent_id === id) {
        result.push(...getDescendants(node.id, source));
     }
    }
  
    return result;
};
```

Expected output of the above when run against '3' is

```
[{ id: "3" }, { id: "3.1", parent_id: "3" }, { id: "3.1.1", parent_id: "3.1" }, { id: "3.1.1.1", parent_id: "3.1.1" }, { id: "3.1.1.1.1", parent_id: "3.1.1.1" }, { id: "3.2", parent_id: "3" }, { id: "bohemian rhapsody", parent_id: "3.2" }]
```

Note: I don't particularly care if this is `breadth first` or `depth first`; just that it is the most performant approach.

Comment: So, judging by `bohemian rhapsody`, the `id` property is inconsistent, and one must always read `parent_id`, correct?

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine yeah id can be whatever, it is rather irrelevant

Comment: A few things I can't help but wonder are (0) how large is the data structure expected to be? Is this a good representation of the size of the dataset, or is this just a trivial(ly small) example. (1) how many times do you expect to need to perform such a query? - I can see many cases where I'd expect the fastest approach to be one which creates an actual tree-like structure from this array of data.

Comment: To build on what @enhzflep said, if you are going to call that method many times on every nodes, then the fastest would be to build once a map of all the descendants per every id, but if you're gonna call only once that method on a single "parent", then that would obviously be slower than "lazily" searching only for that one when required. We need to know more about your actual use case.

Comment: @enhzflep (0) less than 1000 elements in the tree (1) on react re-renders within one element in the tree so fairly frequently

Answer (score 0):

You could perform a search with a single pass.  As your dataset grows large, this would be a more performant solution, particularly in a heavily unbalanced tree as it would be comparing an O(N) solution to an O(N*N) solution.

```
let getDescendants = (id, source) => {
    let result = [];
    let prefix=id + '.';
    for (let node of source) {
        if (node.id === id || node.parent_id === id 
          || node.parent_id && node.parent_id.startsWith(prefix)) {
            result.push(node);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Your optimal solution is affected by how you're representing your tree as a list.  If you were to transform your tree into an object that more closely represents the tree's structure, your recursive approach could be scoped down to the children of your current node without traversing your entire list.

```
[
  {
    id: "1"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    children:[
      {
        id: "2.1",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    children:[
      {  
        id: "3.1",
        children:[
          {
            id: "3.1.1",
            children:[
              {
                id: "3.1.1.1",                  
                children:[
                  {
                    id: "3.1.1.1.1",
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "3.2",
        children:[
          {
            id: "bohemian rhapsody",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: This idea builds on the fact that `node.parent_id.startsWith(prefix)` works. Unfortunately, I need an algorithm that can work with any random ids.

Comment: Makes sense.  If your data resides in memory, then converting it from a flat list to a tree structure would facilitate an efficient traversal algorithm.  It would cost you O(N log N) to build once, but then each of your searches would only cost O(log N + M).  The data structure I described would support any random ids.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution that works without the `.startsWith()` restriction.

```js
const obj=[
  {
id: "1"
  },
  {
id: "2"
  },
  {
id: "3"
  },
  {
id: "two-one",
parent_id: "2"
  },
  {
id: "three-one",
parent_id: "3"
  },
  {
id: "3.2",
parent_id: "3"
  },
  {
id: "3.1.1",
parent_id: "three-one"
  },
  {
id: "3.1.1.1",
parent_id: "3.1.1"
  },
  {
id: "3.1.1.1.1",
parent_id: "3.1.1.1"
  },
  {
id: "bohemian rhapsody",
parent_id: "3.2"
  }
].reduce((a,c)=>(a[c.id]={...c,children:[]},a),{}); // create an object with id as keys
const arr=Object.values(obj);
arr.forEach(o=> // assign children to a parent
 o.parent_id && obj[o.parent_id].children.push(o));
const res=arr.filter(o=>!o.parent_id);

// show resulting object tree:
console.log(res);
```

1. The array is turned into an object with `id`s as keys
2. In a `forEach()` loop over all `.values()` of the object each element is pushed into its parent object's `children` array
3. Lastly, only those values in `obj` that do *not* have a `parent_id` are retained in a `.filter()` operation and stored in the solution array `res`.